# Compress content to the archive root using grunt-contrib-compress

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following directory structure, and I want to zip the content of dev folder and place it in the root of the generated archive without it being wrapped inside a top level folder:

```
_build/    #build scripts
dist/      #destination
dev/       #source
```

**Here is the code (gruntfile.js inside _build):**

```
    compress: {             
         main : {
            options : {
                archive : "../dist/dev.zip"
            },
            files : [
                { expand: true, src : "../dev/**/*" }
            ]
        }     
      }
```

I wish I could zip only the contents of dev folder and place it into dist folder. But when I try to do so I, all the content of dev are zipped inside a root folder.

**Actual generated zip:**

```
dist/
   |____ dev.zip
          |_____ dev/
                  |_____ index.html
                  |_____ styles/style.css
```

**But I want the zip file to be like this:**

```
dist/
   |____ dev.zip
        |_____ index.html
        |_____ styles/style.css
```

You see? the files are being wrapped in a folder(with the same name as the zip) instead of being place into the root of zip file.

Can this be achieved in some way?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Davi, I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 11):

you can do as exposed here : https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/issues/33

For example :

```
compress : {
  main : {
    options : {
      archive : "myapp.zip"
    },
    files : [
      { expand: true, src : "**/*", cwd : "dist/" }
    ]
  }
}
```

will generate myapp.zip in the root path, countaining all files and directory included in /dist, but not the dist directory itself.

Answer (score 6):

another example, more in line with original question:

```
    compress: {
    main: {
        options: {
            archive : "../dist/dev.zip"
        },
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '../dev/',
                src: ['**'],
            }
        ]
    },
},
```

This should give your flat structure:

```
 dist/
   |____ dev.zip
        |_____ index.html
        |_____ styles/style.css
```

checkout this great article on grunt-compress: http://www.charlestonsw.com/what-i-learned-about-grunt-compress/